# How can i correctly setup a local DNS server with BIND?

Tags: dns, bind, webmin

i setup a DNS server via Docker on my OMV NAS.

NAS has static IP: 192.168.0.10 (DNS is reachable via Webmin)

NAS runs BIND-Dns with Webmin in Docker listening on IP: 192.168.0.10:53

In my router i configured IP: 192.168.0.10 as 1st DNS Server (cloudflare as second)

When i do:

```
host@host ~ % nslookup nas.tst.lan 192.168.0.1
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Name:   nas.tst.lan
Address: 192.168.0.10
```

When i do:

```
host@host ~ % sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

an then do:

```
host@host ~ % nslookup nas.tst.lan 192.168.0.1
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

** server can't find nas.tst.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

I assume that is bc of TTL of the old config, but i didn´t change anything. At least not wanted.

When i dig

```
host@host ~ % dig @192.168.0.10 nas.tst.lan 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.168.0.10 nas.tst.lan
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 20926
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nas.tst.lan.       IN  A

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.10#53(192.168.0.10)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 27 11:31:05 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

but when i dig

```
host@host ~ % dig @192.168.0.1 nas.tst.lan  

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.168.0.1 nas.tst.lan
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 6591
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nas.tst.lan.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86159   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020122700 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 27 11:30:41 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

So what did i do wrong?

Comment: Apologies, but what is the problem you are encountering? What do you wish to achieve that isn't happening?

Comment: I want to access my NAS Webinterface when i type "nas.tst.lan" into the Browser URL-Line. But this is not the case whereas it should be, bc dig, host or nslookup tell me, that resolution works. Should i post it as an edit in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Thing can be closed.

The problem was:

There is a difference between WAN-DNS and LAN-DNS in my Router.

I had the WAN-DNS configured as my local DNS. So that was the failure, i could´t understand.

Now the WAN-DNS is back to generic and the LAN-DNS is now configured with 192.168.0.10 and 1.1.1.1 as secondary.

If `dig` runs to the Router it uses the generic DNS of my ISP.

If `dig` runs directly to the local DNS it resolves correctly.

One thought:

Tha LAN-DNS - Function is called [conditional forwarding](https://medium.com/tech-jobs-academy/dns-forwarding-and-conditional-forwarding-f3118bc93984).

This is possible on my, but may not be possible on any router.
So for them i don´t have an answer.